# Implement react-native-web, cant run Web on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-native-web

Hi so i followed [this](https://aureliomerenda.medium.com/create-a-native-web-app-with-react-native-web-419acac86b82) page to implement react-native-web to my project now im stuck at `yarn run test`. There i get following error code:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    D:\Diplomarbeit\React\ChEdu\node_modules\@react-navigation\elements\lib\commonjs\assets\back-icon.png:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){�PNG


    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:20:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.056 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I tried to do it on Mac and on Windows, but in both ways i get an error.

The Main Problem is that I cant run the Web on Mac, on Windows is everything fine but on Mac it isn't working:

Safari:
[image]

Terminal in Visual Studio Code:
[image]

> My code:

```
public/index.html    
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
            <title>React App</title>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <noscript>
                You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
            </noscript>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
    
    </html>

index.native.js

    /**
     * @format
     */
    
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './src/App';
    import {name as appName} from './src/app.json';
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

src/App.js

    import * as React from 'react';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
    
    import HomeScreen from '../Pages/Home';
    import IntroScreen from '../Pages/Intro';
    import MainView from '../Pages/MainView';
    
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
    const MyStack = () => {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{ title: 'ChEdu' }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Intro" component={IntroScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="MainView" component={MainView} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
    
    
    export default MyStack;

src/index.js

    /**
     * @format
     */
    
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
    AppRegistry.runApplication(appName, {
        rootTag: document.getElementById('root'),
    });

index.native.js

    /**
     * @format
     */
    
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './src/App';
    import {name as appName} from './src/app.json';
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

__tests__/App-test.js

    /**
     * @format
     */
    
    import 'react-native';
    import React from 'react';
    import App from '../src/App';
    
    // Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
    import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
    
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      renderer.create(<App />);
    });
```

Tree:
[image: Tree:]

Comment: my GIthub repo: https://github.com/Manubown/ChEdu